# Angular material input type time not working on IE 11, works perfect on all other browsers

Tags: angular, angular-material, internet-explorer-11, angular6

```
<form class="example-form mat-app-background">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" type="time">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Type time not working on IE 11. 
Above code works well on all browsers except IE 11.

Please help.

This is an example straight from [material.angular.io](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview)

Comment: A form needs the attributes `action` and `method`, perhaps IE 11 will accept it if you add these.

Comment: I dont think thats the issue David. Its more related to the input type time which is not supported on IE 11. I am trying to find a work around that. Thanks for trying though.